# How to find the range of $f(t)=e^{-3t} \sin{(2t)}+e^{t/2}t^{7/2}+\sin(t/2)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, graphing-functions, laplace-transform

I need to find the range of these functions

---

$a)f(t)=e^{-3t} \sin{(2t)}+e^{t/2}t^{7/2}+\sin(t/2)$

$b)f(t)=\sin^{2}3t$

---

It is from a laplace transform and app. homework. So I thought it is about laplace transform. But I couldnt correlate.

i.e. laplace transform of second function is $\frac{18}{(s^3 + 36 s)}$. although the range of
$f(t)=\sin^{2}3t$       is
${                                  0\leq y\leq1}$, range of the transform is $y\in R$. What does this have to do with laplace transform?
thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to plot the functions? This should give you an idea of what the answer should be. To answer b), you could remember that the sine function is always between two easy values.

Comment: @BernardMassé Could you elaborate the laplace transform relation?

Comment: At first sight, I don't see any relation between the Laplace Transform and finding the range. Finding the range is a pre-calculus question, while the Laplace Transform is at least a Calc III question.